# One node at a time, in TreeView

Tags: asp.net, treeview, nodes

I have a tree view like this:

```
    1.


      1.1

      1.2

    2.


      2.1

      2.2

....
```

what I want to accomplish is when user click a parent node (for example node 1) every other parent nodes are collapse except the selected node( node 1), in other word, only one subtree is expanded at a time.

I am populating the Menu from Database.
So I use this code in the parent node populating part.

```
MenuTreeView.Nodes.Add(newNode); 
newNode.PopulateOnDemand = true; 
newNode.Collapse();  
newNode.SelectAction= TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand;
```

But this is not working.

Comment: what you tried to acheive this?

Comment: means?
I just want that only one parent node should be open at a time. All the child nodes (which had already been expanded) of all other parent node, should collapse, on expanding a parent node

Comment: The comment asks what, if anything, *you* have *already tried*. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @akashM: if u r mistaken my friend, I am not asking GIVE ME CODE. Just give me an idea for the requirement
Code I will create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one gave me an answer or right suggestion, after trying and doing some R&D, I got the solution.
Posting it, HOPE IT HELPS TO OTHERS.

On the (OnTreeNodeExpand) Node Expand event declare this:-

```
protected void Node_Expand(Object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Node.Parent == null)
                return;
            string strNodeValue = e.Node.Value;
            foreach (TreeNode node in e.Node.Parent.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (node.Value != strNodeValue)
                    node.Collapse();
            }

        }
```

PS: @AakashM:- Never bother to comment if u r not worthy of even a penny.

Thanks StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

In your code-behind use the SelectedNodeChanged event. Assuming you have a TreeView called TreeView1, loop through all nodes, collapse them all, and then expand the selected one.

```
    Protected Sub TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TreeView1.SelectedNodeChanged
        For Each tn As TreeNode In TreeView1.Nodes
            tn.Collapse()
        Next
        TreeView1.SelectedNode.Expand()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thnx mccrager, for trying to help. But it actually was not solving my case.

Comment: My solution certainly does work. Only thing I overlooked was that you posted C# and I gave you VB.NET.

Comment: I did not tell your solution is wrong. Just for my specific case (requirement), it was not giving the desired result. thats it. Your code could be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

BEST ANSWER REALLY IT WORK OUT, if one parent node is expand other parent node will get collpase.

In the C#:

```
PAGE LOAD()
{
    Treeviewdata.CollapseAll();
}
```

---

```
protected void Treeviewdata_TreeNodeExpanded(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs 
{
    e.Node.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand;
}
```